# Matlab toString equivalent?

Tags: matlab, tostring

Is there any way to convert any object to it's string representation in Matlab?

I tried

```
matlab.unittest.diagnostics.ConstraintDiagnostic.getDisplayableString
```

but sometimes it produces HTML code like this

```
0×0 empty <a href="matlab:helpPopup char" style="font-weight:bold">char</a> array
```

Is it possible to get only plain text in result?

Comment: What object types do you want to convert from? How do you define "string representation" for these objects?

Comment: Are you looking for serialization or do you just want to display object properties (as in `whos`)?

Comment: I think, you are looking similar to c# "ToString()" method. I think, you have to define your own.

Comment: @Wolfie all types; the same as they printed if you type variable with this object

Comment: @User1551892 why? Matlab is a console application. It has ability to print as string somewhere inside

Comment: Are you asking about a [Custom Display Interface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/custom-display-interface.html)?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly what you want, but I use this kind of call for generating general purpose (text) error messages when the object type can vary. It calls `disp()` and captures the text output:

```
x = containers.Map({'A','B'}, [1,2]); % Example object - could be anything    
s = evalc('disp(x)');
```

Now this uses `evalc()` which is rather clumsy and is never going to be quick and the 'x' is buried in a string. But it is convenient....

Comment: If `x` is a large matrix, that is going to be a very large string... But maybe it is what OP is after?